# Why $n^{d(n)/2}$ is not getting satisfied?

Tags: number-theory

Respected all.

We know that the product of all positive divisors of $n\in \mathbb N$ is $n^{d(n)/2}$ where $d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors on $n$.

What will happen if $d(n)=odd$ say we consider $n=100$. Then the product is 
$1\times 2\times 4\times 5\times 10\times 20\times 25\times 50\times 100=1\times 2\times 4\times 5\times 10\times \frac{100}{5}\times \frac{100}{4}\times \frac{100}{2}\times \frac{100}{1}=100^4\times 10$ whereas the formula is $100^{9/2}$ ....

What so wrong here can someone tell me?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong: $d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a square.  And in this case $n^{d(n)/2}$ is still an integer.

For example,
$$100^{9/2}=100^{4+(1/2)}=100^4\times100^{1/2}=100^4\times10\ .$$

Comment: got that. thanks